# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

In my project their are two Screens.

First Screen contains a floating Action Button, onclick navigates to second screen having form and on submitting the form. A Map is created with Key and value as the fields in the form. And map is added to the list.

Now using the Navigator. pop function the list is passed to the first screen and On printing the list on the console, error message  comes saying,

Error: The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' in Flutter

Code:
First Screen:

```
class donateNow extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _donateNowState createState() => _donateNowState();
}

class _donateNowState extends State<donateNow>{
   List medicineCart = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Donate Medicine'),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        icon:Icon(Icons.add),
        label: Text('Add Medicine'),
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 10.0,
        splashColor: kPrimaryLightColor,
        onPressed: (){
          _navigateAndDisplayMedicine(context);
        }
      ),
    );
  }

  _navigateAndDisplayMedicine(BuildContext context) async{
    List<dynamic> newList = await Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => medicineDetails()),
    );
    print('Medicine:'+ newList.toString());
  }
}
```

Second Screen:

```
class medicineDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => medicineDetailsState();
}

class medicineDetailsState extends State<medicineDetails> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 List medicineCart = [];
  TextEditingController medName = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController qty = new TextEditingController();
  
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add Medicine"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
            
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: false,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  debugPrint('Something change');
                },
                controller: medName,
                validator: (value){
                  if(value.isEmpty)
                    return kMedicineNameNullError;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Medicine Name with Strength',
                    labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                    hintText: 'Enter Medicine Name',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
              ),

            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 15.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                controller: qty,
                validator: (value){
                  int val = int.parse(value);
                  if(value.isEmpty)
                    return kQuantityNullError;
                  else if(val<4){
                    return kMinimumQuantityError;
                  }
                },
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Quantity',
                    labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                    hintText: 'Enter the quantity',
                    border:
                    OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
              ),
            ),



              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    // SaveButton(),
                    Expanded(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                            color: Color(0xFF574FC4),
                            textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                            child: Text(
                              'Save',
                              textScaleFactor: 2.0,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                                _formKey.currentState.save();
                                KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(context);
                                var map = {
                                  'Medicine Name': medName.text,
                                  'Date': expDate.text,
                                  'Quantity Type': qtyType,
                                  'Quantity': qty.text,
                                };
                                medicineCart.add(map);
                                Navigator.pop(context,medicineCart);
                                debugPrint('Save Clicked');
                              }
                            })),
                    
                    Expanded(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                            color: Color(0xFF574FC4),
                            textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                            child: Text(
                              'Delete',
                              textScaleFactor: 2.0,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                debugPrint('Delete Clicked');
                                //print(medicineCart);
                                
                              });
                            }))
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're trying to assign a `List<dynamic>` to a String variable - which seems to be done when you're trying to pass `medicineCart` on Navigator.pop(). A quick workaround here is to encode your List to String then  decode it back again using [jsonEncode()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) and [jsonDecode()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html).